# Get type of record from standard controller without accessing record?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, standardcontroller

I've got a component which is used on multiple object types in their visualforce pages. I have a controller which provides some data, and another to add some relevant fields.

The controller which adds some fields, now needs to conditionally add a field, based solely on the object type. Seems pretty simple, right? Lets just check the type of the record from `getRecord()` - wait, doing that causes a `Cannot Modify Record before calling addFields()` error. How about `getId()`? Works great, except for having to cast the return (a string) to an id. Oh wait, nope! It doesn't work if the record doesn't have an id.

Now I'm kind of stuck - how do I tell the object type of a record without accessing it, or its id? I don't see any methods for accessing this data in the standard controller class.

I've considered some funky methods, such as providing this data via attributes to the controller or trying to serialize the controller/record and parse the result sniffing for types, but these would access the record before calling `getFields`. In theory I could rely less on the field and use a fieldset instead, but I still need to know what Object in working with.

Heres some sample code:

```
public class FieldProvider {
    public FieldProvider(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            List<String> fields = new List<String>{
                'Field__c',
                'Another_Field__c',
                'Third_Field__c'
            };

            // Fails if Id is null 
            // Can't use `getRecord` before calling `addFields`
            if (Id.valueOf(controller.getId()).getsObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('Conditional__c')) {
                fields.add('Conditional__c');
            }

            if (!Test.IsRunningTest()) { controller.addFields(fields); }
    }
}
```

Tl;dr: I need to identify the type of this record, so I can tell if this field exists on the given object type. But, I can't access the record or its id.

Comment: Yeah with an `Id`, it's simple, but without, not so much. Why not just move everything to dynamic SOQL? Is that an option?

Comment: I don't think so, there's two other extensions using the same pattern on the page. Plus it has to use the standard controller, otherwise I would have replaced the separate controllers with a single one already.

Comment: You don't really need the field to be queried when it's new, though. Or do you get an exception in that case? Can you just do your Id check in the case where `getId()` returns a value? Calling `addFields` should essentially do nothing when you pass in a record not yet saved to the database.

Comment: I need the field to be added via `addFields` or trying to use it on the page results in an exception. Without an id, I'm not able to use this field on a new page, which is the use case for the field (its a campaign lookup for marketing to use, but the name of the field varies by object).

Comment: My question was, what is the type of exception? You could possibly catch it as a workaround, though the approach you found is much more elegant.

Comment: Why would you need to "addFields" if it's a new record? There's no purpose in doing so, since you can't query a record that doesn't exist.

Comment: So the underlying exception is a `NullPointerException` caused by `String.ValueOf(null)`. You can catch it, but then the dynamic reference in the component would fail & cause another exception. Or so I thought? For some reason I was under the impression that you need to call `addFields` in all contexts, but i guess you don't for new records. I think at one point I may have had an issue which caused me to structure my code like this, and then I never questioned it going back.

Comment: I can confirm that NOT adding the field if the Id is null does not prevent the field from being rendered on the layout, but not adding the field on an edit view causes an exception. I guess there is a query being run under the surface that needs to be modified for edit records, but not new records. If either of you wants to post an answer describing why, or the sequencing of the `addFields`, I'd appreciate it, clearly I still have a lot to learn!

Comment: This is exactly why I was trying to figure out which exception you were running into. That's quite easy to work around. I thought you were running into an exception at a different step in the flow control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just check if `getId` returns a value. Note that you can assign a `String` value to an `Id` variable.

```
Id recordId = controller.getId();
SObjectType sObjectType = (recordId == null) ?
    null : recordId.getSObjectType();

if (sObjectType == Account.SObjectType || sObjectType == Contact.SObjectType)
{
    fields.add('MyField__c');
}
```

Comment: I guess I confused the usage of the method.The documentation doesn't mention anything about this being used to make a query, the exact line is `"This method adds a reference to each field specified in fieldNames so that the controller can explicitly access those fields as well."` Note the "access", not query. I assumed that the fields were used for more than just a basic query, and that a "reference" of some kind was needed for EVERY field regardless of context (none is given on that page, ie "dont call this for new records").

Comment: Yep. It's a query. Sounds like an informative morning. :)

Answer (score 3):

So, I guess the only way to get the type of an object in a `ApexPages.StandardController` without accessing the record itself is to use `String.ValueOf` to get a text representation of the object underneath. Thankfully, someone had the foresight to make this useful information.

```
String objectType = String.valueOf(controller);
// This string looks like this:
// "ApexPages.StandardController[Account]"
// So we can "parse" it and get that object name, 
// or we can use `Contains` to try and find a name inside the string 

if (objectType.contains('[Lead]')) {
    // Could also create new instance, or get describe by name 
    fields.add('Conditional__c');
} else if (objectType.contains('[Account]')) {
    // Doesn't have field, don't add anything 
} else if (objectType.contains('[Contact]')) {
    fields.add('Conditional'); // Standard field, as example 
}
```

This doesn't count as accessing the record and allows the controller to describe its type, even though it feels really brittle. Would really like another method to figure this out.

---

So this is actually a non-issue. `AddFields` is only nessescary when information has to be pulled out of the database, and does not affect the rendering of "new record" pages when not used. So, for any record with a valid ID, you can call the methods against the Id, for the rest of the records, you can just skip the call.

See: [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: So simple. What an interesting find. I'd probably use regex instead but very neat trick! `if (Pattern.compile('ApexPages.StandardController[(Account|Contact)]').matcher(String.valueOf(controller)).find()) { fields.add('Condditional__c') }`

Comment: Can't take credit for this one, I think I found the `String.ValueOf` trick somewhere else on the network.